# Is it $x-[x]-\frac{1}{2}$ or $x-[x]+1$ in the derivation of the Euler Summation formula

Tags: asymptotics

The theorem on the Euler Maclaurin Summation formula usually involves the term $x-\lfloor x\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}$, however in some other text, I sometimes also see the term $x-\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ instead.

I came across this issue after looking at two different derivation of the formula /The first proof came from the book:  *An introduction to Sequences, Series, and Improper Integrals* by: O.E. Stanaitis pp.74-75

If $f(x)$ possesses a continuous derivative $f'(x)$ on $[1,n]$, then

$\sum_{s=1}^{n} f(x) = \int_{1}^{n} f(x)dx + \int_{1}^{n} (x-\lfloor x\rfloor- \frac{1}{2})f'(x)dx + \frac{1}{2} [f(1)+f(n)]$

The proof goes as follows:

> The obvious equality 
> $\int_{\mu}^{\mu +1} (x-\mu- \frac{1}{2})f'(x)dx=(x-\mu- \frac{1}{2})f(x)\Big|_{x=\mu}^{x=\mu+1} - \int_{\mu}^{\mu +1} f(x)dx$ obtained by partial integration holds for $\mu=1,2,\dots,n-1.$ 
> In the integrand on the left we can put $\mu=\lfloor x\rfloor$ for $\mu \leq x < \mu + 1.$  Since $x-\lfloor x\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}$ differs from $x-\mu-\frac{1}{2}$ only at one point $x=\mu +1$ on the intervale $[\mu, \mu+1],$ and this does not change the value of the integral, we get 
> $\frac{1}{2} [f(\mu)+f(\mu+1)]=\int_{\mu}^{\mu + 1} f(x)dx + \int_{\mu}^{\mu + 1} (x-\lfloor x\rfloor - \frac{1}{2})f'(x)dx$ 
> Addition of the relations for $\mu=1,2,\dots,n-1,$ and then of the term $\frac{1}{2} [f(1)+f(n)]$ to both sides yields the Euler's summation formula.

In the book [*Divergent Series* by G.H. Hardy, pp.318-319, "Euler Maclaurin summation" in search box,](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Divergent_Series/fa9QaUJWLz0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)  He present the formula as follows.  I will reproduce the first portion of the proof since my question pertains to that.

> We suppose first that $0 < a \leq 1,$ that $f'(x)$ is continuous for $x \geq a,$ that $f > 0,$ $f' <0,$ and that $f\rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty.$  Then
> $\int_{1}^{x} |f'(t)|dt=-\int_{1}^{x} f'(t)dt=f(1)-f(x)\rightarrow f(1)$ when $x\rightarrow \infty,$ so that $\int_{1}^{\infty} |f'(t)|dt=f(1) <\infty.$
> if $y=x-[x],$ so that $y=x-m+1$ for $m-1 \leq x < m,$ then $0 \leq y < 1$ and $J= \int_{1}^{\infty} yf'(x)dx$ is absolutely convergent.  Also 
> $j_m = f(m)-\int_{m-1}^{m} f(x)dx=\int_{m-1}^{m} \{f(m)-f(x)\}dx=\int_{m-1}^{m} \{f(m)-f(x)\}\frac{dy}{dx}dx= \int_{m-1}^{m} yf'(x)dx,$
> $\sum_{m=2}^{n} f(m)-\int_{1}^{n} f(x)dx=\sum_{m=2}^{n} j_m = \int_{1}^{n} (x-[x])f'(x)dx.$  It follows that, if $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt,$  $(*)$ then $\sum_{m=1}^{n} f(m)-F(n) \rightarrow f(1)-F(1) + J$ $(**)$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$  If our conditions are satisfied for every $a > 0,$ and $f(x)$ is integrable down to $0,$ we may take $a=0$ in $(*)$ and $(**).$

{Hardy uses $m$ to denote $\lfloor x \rfloor$, since if $m=\lfloor x \rfloor$.    $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x < \lfloor x \rfloor +1,$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor -1 \leq x < \lfloor x \rfloor,$}

What I would like clarification on is this; does it matter that for the greatest integer function $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, whether the fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ is subtracted from $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ or a value $\frac{1}{2} \leq \theta < 1$ is added to $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.  
  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @jjagmath I also posted the other question you linked to because I thought it was a separate,question and I don't want to make a post that is super long.   I think this one is a bit simpler in terms of what I am asking.